# Map from sequence to set

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, notation, terminology

I'm writing something up and I'm just wondering if there's a notation and/or name for the function which maps the elements of a sequence $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$ (or the finite sequence $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$) to the set which contains all of the same elements $\{a_1, a_2, \dots\}$.

I'm fine with just making up a notation, but I feel like this might be something someone has already come up with a standard symbol for, though a quick Google search didn't find me one.

Comment: If you look at a sequence as $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$, then it's just the image.

Comment: If you treat a sequence as a function $f\colon \mathbb N \to S$, then what you are looking for is simply the image of $f$, e.g., $\Im (f)$ if you like fancy stuff.

Comment: OK.  I didn't think of that.  Thanks.  If one of you writes that up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Nah, it's too short (I don't need the points).  Feel free to write it yourself and accept it.

Comment: I made it a community-wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at a sequence as $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$, then it's just the image.